# Error installing Angular 2 CLI

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

I'm trying to install the Angular 2 CLI on a El Capitan machine with:
 **node 7.10.0** and **npm 5.0**.

I get the following recursive error during installation:

> gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp"
>   gyp verb tmpdir == cwd automatically will remove dev files after to save disk space
>   gyp verb command install [ '8.0.0' ]
>   gyp verb install input version string "8.0.0"
>   gyp verb install installing version: 8.0.0
>   gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
>   gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 8.0.0
>   gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.0.0
>   gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.0.0"
>   gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp"
>   gyp verb tmpdir == cwd automatically will remove dev files after to save disk space
>   gyp verb command install [ '8.0.0' ]
>   gyp verb install input version string "8.0.0"
>   gyp verb install installing version: 8.0.0
>   gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
>   gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 8.0.0
>   gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.0.0
>   gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.0.0"
>   gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp"
>   gyp verb tmpdir == cwd automatically will remove dev files after to save disk space
>   gyp verb command install [ '8.0.0' ]
>   gyp verb install input version string "8.0.0"
>   gyp verb install installing version: 8.0.0
>   gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
>   gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 8.0.0
>   gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.0.0
>   gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.0.0"
>   gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp"
>   gyp verb tmpdir == cwd automatically will remove dev files after to save disk space
>   gyp verb command install [ '8.0.0' ]
>   gyp verb install input version string "8.0.0"
>   gyp verb install installing version: 8.0.0
>   gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
>   gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 8.0.0
>   gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.0.0

I've uninstalled it by using

```
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

and reinstalled it by using

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Insight into what may be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: `npm` 5.0 seems to be the issue. I had to downgrade (3.10 with node 6.11) to get my install to work on Mint.

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/454

Comment: @R.Richards how did you downgrade to 3.1?

Comment: I used the Software Manager in Mint to do the uninstall, then I followed the install instructions [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) to install node 6.11 (6.x).

Answer (score 1):

`sudo npm install --unsafe-perm --verbose -g @angular/cli`

Did the trick. Workaround works for now.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to resolve this is to install `gyp` and `@angular/cli` explicitly.

```
sudo npm install gyp @angular/cli -g
```

If it fails again, try to install `gyp` first and then the CLI.